# Is topic communcation zero-copy if running multiple nodelets standalone? (instead of a manager)

Tags: ros, nodelet, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am confused by the [Nodelet Docs](http://wiki.ros.org/nodelet) regarding the two possibilities to run a nodelet (1.4 Basic Usage). Apparently, one can either

- launch one nodelet manager and load multiple nodelets into this manager *or*
- launch multiple standalone nodelets in different nodes.

**Is the communication between nodelets still zero-copy, if I launch
them as standalone nodelets?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259742/is-topic-communcation-zero-copy-if-running-multiple-nodelets-standalone?-(instead-of-a-manager)/) by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 185 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, the Data will be copied in this case. Zero copy publish/subscribe ist only possible if both nodelets Run in the Same process, i.e. in one node...

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [takahashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/23199/takahashi/) on 2017-04-21**:
thanks for the answer. but what is the purpose then of standalone nodelets? as far as I understood, the big advantage of nodelets over nodes is the zero-copy transport..

**Comment by [jespestana](https://answers.ros.org/users/4328/jespestana/) on 2019-02-13**:
The advantage of standalone nodelets, is that you program the nodelet but can still run your module as a node. This maybe interesting for debugging porpuses...

You only get the zero-copy transport capability when the nodelets are started on the same nodelet_manager process.